New Lightning record page fails to render but Edit/View displays fine
I have a simple Case Lightning Record Page that looks like this:


Page is activated

But when I click on New from the Cases tab or any Cases listview/related list, the page refuses to render - a ghostly page.

If I click on an existing Case (i.e. View), the page renders fine

It also renders fine on Edit of an existing Case.

What's the deal with inability to render for the New action?

You can see from the OP screenshot that there is conditional formatting applied to a field called Account_Website__c defined as a formula Account.Website
The conditional formatting rule is (display sad face if case is not closed) - hence true for new cases.

What I learned
When a Case is New (via New button on Case tab/listview/related list/global action)

There is no Account (i.e. Case.AccountId is null so the field  Case.Account_Website__c` formula would render as null)
But ... SFDC chokes and refuses to display the lightning form to create a new record. Remove the conditional formatting field rule and the page displays just fine in this use case.

When a Case is New (via New button on the Account's related list)

Case.AccountId is defaulted by SFDC before the new form is displayed and
The formula field Case.Account_Website__c renders as null as there's no value in Account.Website
The new form renders correctly even with the conditional field formatting rule


The SFDC Doc on conditional formatting considerations states:

You can’t add conditional formatting to cross-object fields, nor can you select cross-object fields when creating rules.

Note that the link to cross-object fields talks about cross-object fields on dynamic forms, not formula fields that happen to be cross-object.
I did not see a Known Issue for this and in my book, this is a bug -- a New record form should render regardless of the presence of conditional formatting rules
Workarounds

Remove the conditional field formatting rule on any formula field that happens to reference a cross-object that might be null at run time (as in a Contact w/o an Account, a Case w/o an Account, etc)
Use dynamic visibility to not render the cross-object field with conditional field formatting if the record is "new" (i.e. has no ID or auto-number field)

